# How to schedule an email message from a webform email address

Tags: webforms

Need: Schedule an email message to anyone that completes my WEBFORM +2 days in the future.

I got this to work 90% of the way. Emails are being scheduled, but the 'TO:' email address is `[webform:val-email_address]` instead of the email address from the webform.

My questions are:

- What value to I use in the COMPONENT to successfully schedule the email to the email address from the webform?
- Do I need to add an ELEMENT or additional ACTIONS?

I created a RULE with

```
Event: "After a webform has been submitted"

Conditions: None

Actions:    
Elements - Schedule component evaluation
Parameter: Component: Schedule email to applicant..., Scheduled evaluation date: +2 day

Component:
Actions
Sent Email
```

Thank you in advance for your help. Blessings!